# How to get relative path of file in solution?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a schema that I have added to my Sequential Workflow solution. Currently, when I access the schema it is hard coded to a location on my c drive.

```
doc.Schemas.Add(@"http://usdoj.gov/leisp/lexs/publishdiscover/3.1", @"C:\Code\NSI\xsd\lexs\publish-discover\3.1\publish-discover.xsd");
```

I would like to upload this schema to a library for future use. However, this sequential workflow has to be used on many different computers, all of which will not contain the schema in the location that I have on my computer. So I added the schema to my workflow project but when I try to call on it using a relative path with the following code:

```
doc.Schemas.Add(@"http://usdoj.gov/leisp/lexs/publishdiscover/3.1", @"..\Schemas\publish-discover.xsd");
```

I get the error: "c:\windows\system32\Schemas\publish-discover.xsd". I want to be able to access the schema without having to provide a local hard coded path so I can upload it to a library and have the final wsp file work on multiple machines.

Comment: Basically I am trying to access a file, any file, that I have added to my solution, but when I type in the path "../folder/file.xsd" Visual Studio defaults to the c:\windows\system32 folder. I want to know how to add a file to my solution and access it without having provide a path from the local hard disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the schema as an embedded resource in your solution. Then using `Properties.Resources.WhateverYouNameTheResource` you can open it in code. This way the schema will get deployed with your assembly. More on embedded resources here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht9h2dk8.aspx

Comment: Thank you I tried that and it worked, but it returned a string of the schema. When I try to access the schema with this line of code doc.Schemas.Add(@"ijis-isesar/1.5";, NSI_FCS_Workflow.Properties.Resources.sari); it throws an exception stating it wants a url to the path of the schema rather then the schema in string form. To get around this I passed the string to the a StringReader and then passed that to an XmlReader and it worked great.

Answer (score 1):

You can provision the file into a document library and refer the file via path which is common for all users. You can do this via  in your feature's element file. Example below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231567.aspx

Comment: Thank you, I tried that, and the file is there, but when I try to access it with code doc.Schemas.Add(@"http://ijis-isesar/1.5", @"http://yak/NSI_FCS_Bin/sari.xsd"); I get a 401 Unauthorized error. However, if I type the address into IE, I can access the file just fine and it prompts me to download it. Is there something else I have to do to get around the 401 error? I made sure I was logged in before running the code.